# render form_widget many times

Tags: symfony, twig

i want to render a form_widget many times in different div but always it render once , i try also to submit the form with out form_widget but i got csrf error

```
{% for pub in pub %}
{% for publisher in publisher %}
{% if ( pub.publisher is same as  ( publisher  ) ) %}
<div class="box-footer">
<form action="{{ path('commentaire_create',{ "id": pub.id}) }}" {{ 

form_enctype(formpub) }} method="POST" >
    <img class="img-responsive img-circle img-sm" src="dist/img/user4-128x128.jpg" alt="alt text">
    <div class="img-push">

{{ form_widget(formcom.statu,{'attr': {'class': 'form-control input-sm','placeholder': "Votre commentaire ...",'id':pub.id ,'name':pub.id }})}}
{{ form_rest(formcom) }}
<!-- <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Press enter to post comment">-->
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
 </div>
 {% endif %}                                        
{% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
```

any help ?

Answer (score 0):

What is the goal of this ?

Yes you can try, but your Form will not validate this if you are adding some fields.

If you want to do it, check setRendered on a field form (to set to false after render it, to re-render it again)

Answer (score 0):

Each of your forms should be unique, because for example Symfony generate id for your form elements, so rendering several times a single form would create duplicate ids. To *name* your form, you should use `createNamed` or `createNamedBuilder` from the Form Factory.

### If you create your form using the Form Builder:

```
$forms = array();
foreach ($pubs as $pub) {
    $id = $pub->getId();

    $forms[$id] = $this->container->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder("pub-{$id}", 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FormType', $pub)
        ->add('comment', TextType::class)
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Save'))
        ->getForm();
}
```

### If you create your form using a Form Type

```
$forms = array();
foreach ($pubs as $pub) {
    $id = $pub->getId();
    $forms[$id] = $this->container->get('form.factory')->createNamed("pub-{$id}", new PubType(), $pub);
}
```